# How to use two initStmt in for-loop?

Tags: go, tree

[Initstmt](https://golang.org/ref/spec#InitStmt) in foor loop

Goal is to add two trees and return a new tree, in the below code:

```
/*
        3                               3
      /   \                           /   \
     /     \                         /     \
    1       2                       1       2
          /   \                            /
         /     \                          /
        1       1                        1

*/

/*
    1) Tree has root label and list of branches
    2) Each branch is again a tree
*/

type Tree struct {
    rootLabel int
    branches  []Tree
}

func addTrees(t1 Tree, t2 Tree) Tree {
    if isLeaf(t1) {
        return Tree{}
    }
    firstTreeBranches := branches(t1)
    secondTreeBranches := branches(t2)
    for branch1:= firstTreeBranches[0], branch2:= secondTreeBranches[0];;{
            
    }
}

func branches(t Tree) []Tree {
    return t.branches
}
```

---

I would like to make recursive call `addTrees(branch1,branch2)` in the above code.

How to use for-loop syntax to fetch branches from two trees?

Comment: why not have them both at the beginning of the `for` loop. (i.e. after the `{` or inside the loop)

Comment: @ifnotak inside the loop, initstmt will execute every loop iteration. initstmt should execute only once, for given for-loop

Comment: sorry, didn't read properly at first. Added an answer!

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this using the following:

```golang
for branch1, branch2 := firstTreeBranches[0], secondTreeBranches[0] ; ; {
    ...
}
```

[Try it on the playground](https://play.golang.org/p/JZuJVng-dpl). Refer to [Variable declaration](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Variable_declarations) for more infomation.